# Python: Print to one line with time delay between prints

Tags: python, console, formatting, format, string-formatting

I want to make (for fun) python print out 'LOADING...' to console. The twist is that I want to print it out letter by letter with sleep time between them of 0.1 seconds (ish). So far I did this:

```
from time import sleep
print('L') ; sleep(0.1)
print('O') ; sleep(0.1)
print('A') ; sleep(0.1)
etc...
```

However that prints it to separate lines each.

Also I cant just type `print('LOADING...')` since it will print instantaneously, not letter by letter with `sleep(0.1)` in between.

The example is trivial but it raises a more general question: Is it possible to print multiple strings to one line with other function being executed in between the string prints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also simply try this

```
from time import sleep
loading = 'LOADING...'
for i in range(10):
    print(loading[i], sep=' ', end=' ', flush=True); sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 7):

In Python2, if you put a comma after the string, print does not add a new line. However, the output may be buffered, so to see the character printed slowly, you may also need to flush stdout:

```
from time import sleep
import sys
print 'L',
sys.stdout.flush()
sleep(0.1)
```

So to print some text slowly, you could use a `for-loop` like this:

```
from time import sleep
import sys

def print_slowly(text):
    for c in text:
        print c,
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sleep(0.5)

print_slowly('LOA')
```

In Python3, change

```
print c,
```

to

```
print(c, end='')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from time import sleep

myList = ['Let this be the first line', 'Followed by a second line', 'and a third line']

for s in myList:
    print(s) ; sleep(0.6)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've written a quite large program and want to add that feature, then overwrite the builtin function `print`

```
python_print = print
def print(txt):
    text = str(txt)
    for c in text:
        python_print(c, end="", flush=True)
        time.sleep(random.randint(2, 8)/100)
    python_print()
```

This function ensures that

1. The output is flushed (no need of the sys module)
2. After one character was written, there is a delay of 0.02 to 0.08 seconds.
3. The actual behavior of the print function is kept (so you can make it print arrays and modules) - because of the str() call, though there are some exceptions.

What this function cannot do:

You can't call print like this anymore because it only takes one argument:

```
print("Hello", "World")
```

Feel free to add that feature or have a look at *someone implemented that*:
https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html

Oh and if you haven't noticed yet - use python_print() if delayed text is inapropriate in some cases.

*I wonder why python_print is not shallow-cloned. May anyone explain?*

--

## Someone implemented that :)

Someone has called my approach (I think especially the *args) cute and worked for at least 30 minutes to get something even better which is considerably larger (please, don't call it bloated though). I didn't test it, but it seems working well to my eyes.

So with that code you'll be able to use print like print("Hello", "World") again.

Credits to: @MarcinKonowalczyk =>
https://gist.github.com/MarcinKonowalczyk/48a08fe2492b88df184decf427fd2caf

Thank you for taking your time.

## Now Run a Function While Loading

In order to run something (otherwise *Loading* would be useless anyway I guess) while it's printing, you can use the `threading` module.

So, without further ado, let's quickly get started.

```
import threading

def load():
  # do I/O blocking stuff here

threading.Thread(target=load).start() # returns the thread object 
# and runs start() to launch the function load() non-blocking.
print("LOADING...")
```

You may consider removing the random delay from my function which is untypical for a `LOADING...` screen.

If you don't need to wait until the LOADING... is done to *close* the program easily with `ctrl-c`, you can change the `daemon` attribute to `True`. Please note that, if the **main thread** finishes, your other thread will stop *forcefully*.

Here's an example to how you could to that:

```
loadingThread = Threading.thread(target=load)
loadingThread.daemon = True
loadingThread.start()

print("LOADING...")
loadingThread.join() # wait for the loadingThread to finish
```

With this, the program will exit just fine, however you may have to catch KeyboardInterrupt:

```
try:
    loadingThread.join()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # cleanup stuff here or just *pass*
finally: # optional, runs *always*
    # cleanup stuff here
```

Comment: Cute. So, you don't actually need *args and **kwargs but can just make your printer have the same signature as the built-in print. Here is a version with appropriate signature: https://gist.github.com/MarcinKonowalczyk/48a08fe2492b88df184decf427fd2caf The `flush` keyword has a different default value because otherwise its python buffering breaks the whole thing. I've also added `patch` and `unpatch` functions to be able to switch this on and off at will (better way of doing it would be a context namer protocol i guess but this is jsut for fun so it matters little).

Comment: Oh, i don't know what you mean about the `python_print` being shallow-cloned in your example.

Comment: @MarcinKonowalczyk - if python_print = print would be shallow cloned, python_print should *always* have the same value as print (I guess you know what I mean - `a = b; a += 1; a == b => True`) - however python_print contains the original function and is not linked to the new print. That's confusing me.

Comment: @MarcinKonowalczyk I edited my answer and added *someone has implemented that*. I hope it's okay to you, I'll remove it if you like me to do that.

Comment: `python -c 'a = b; a += 1; print(a == b)'` fails with `NameError`. `python -c 'b = 1; a = b; a += 1; print(a == b)'` which prints False (not True). I assume though you meant a behaviour like the one you'd get from objects: `python -c 'O = type("O", (object,), {"v": 1}); b = O; a = b; a.v += 1; print(a == b and a.v == b.v)'` which prints True (excuse the [nasty class definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45087505/2531987). Its equivalent to `class O: v = 1` but works in -c string). Long story short, have a look at [this](https://youtu.be/_AEJHKGk9ns) talk for explanation.

Comment: @MarcinKonowalczyk to your question whether it is possible to run a function while it's writing - that is possible, however needs the threading module. I'll add that to my comment, too.

Answer (score 0):

Updated to print all the letters on one line.

```
from time import sleep
import sys
sys.stdout.write ('L') ; sleep(0.1)
sys.stdout.write ('O') ; sleep(0.1)
sys.stdout.write ('A') ; sleep(0.1)
...
sys.stdout.write ('\n')
```

etc...

or even:

```
from time import sleep
import sys
output = 'LOA...'
for char in output:
    sys.stdout.write ('%s' % char)
    sleep (0.1)

sys.stdout.write ('\n')
```

Comment: This prints out on separate lines, which is not what the question is asking for

Answer (score 0):

To type a string one letter at a time all you've got to do is this:

```
import sys 
import time

yourWords = "whatever you want to type letter by letter"

for char in yourWords:
sys.stdout.write(char)
time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: that would not work.... because you forget to indent after the for and you don't flush the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import sys

def code(text, delay=0.07):
    for c in text:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(delay)
    print()
```

Instead of print type code

Comment: you could use `print(flush=True)` as stated in my answer..