# How to print a multiline string one line at a time with a delay?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
string = """This is a
very long string,
containing commas,
that I split up
for readability"""
```

I want to output the above example, one line at a time, with a delay of say 0.5 seconds. I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432478/python-print-to-one-line-with-time-delay-between-prints) which does the same but prints characters with a delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split lines; iterate each line while printing it, then sleep after printing.

```
import time

string = """This is a
very long string,
containing commas,
that I split up
for readability"""

for line in string.splitlines():
    print(line)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```