# Build a class with an attribute in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

How do I write a one-liner for the following?

```
class MyClass(): 
    content = {}
obj = MyClass()
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do that ungodly thing?

Comment: @zwer To pull "funnies"(do one liners) in university python courses

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `type` as an alternative way to create a class:

```
MyClass = type('MyClass', (object,), {'content':{}})
obj = MyClass()
```

or, in one line without binding the class to a name:

```
obj = type('MyClass', (object,), {'content':{}})()
```

The first argument being the name, the second the bases and the third the class namespace.