# How can I print text so it looks like it's being typed out?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a python program that will print out each letter in a string with a small pause in between each letter to make it look like it's live typing. Instead of the print() function which just adds the whole line(s) of text at once.

I have researched this quite a bit and it's very difficult to find a solid answer.
One way to do this would just be to make a bunch of print functions with time.sleep() in between them,

But they print on different lines, even if you could get these to print on the same line it would be very inefficient.
So how can I do this?

Comment: ... google: `python output text with delay in console` - 1st hit: [python-print-to-one-line-with-time-delay-between-prints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432478/python-print-to-one-line-with-time-delay-between-prints)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is actually really easy, You can use this,

```
import time
string = ("Hey user whatup? Where are you!")
for char in string:
    print(char, end='')
    time.sleep(.01)
```

you can change the time in time.sleep(.01) to make it faster or slower.

you can also make a random human typing effect like this,

```
import time
import random
import sys

def fake_type(words):
    words += "\n"
    for char in words:
        time.sleep(random.choice([
          0.3, 0.11, 0.08, 0.07, 0.07,
          0.07, 0.06, 0.06, 0.05, 0.01
        ]))
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)

fake_type("Example of randomly timed characters to create a human-like typing effect.")
fake_type("It works better when you have multiple lines to genererate more reading space.")
```

Comment: Did you answer your own question immediately after posting it?

Comment: I used the answer your own question option when asking my question.

Comment: @JuanC There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @JuanC https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I have searched stack overflow and there doesn't seem to be a good answer for this question.

Comment: Nice! Didn't know it was encouraged even if you knew the answer beforehand.